# FormView data binding and QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, model-binding, formview

I'm using ASP.NET Model Binding. My page accepts an encrypted parameter in the QueryString that, when decrypted, contains the ID of the record that needs to be loaded in the `FormView`. I'm not sure how to pass this ID value to the `SelectMethod`, which is called indirectly by the Model Binding framework. One easy way is to store the decrypted ID value in a Session variable and then use it in the `SelectMethod` (thus ignoring the id parameter passed in by the framework), but that looks a bit non-standard. Is there a standard approach for this common scenario?

This is how the `SelectMethod` looks like:

```
public MyEntity MyFormView_GetItem(int id)
{
    //return the data object after querying your data source through EF or whatever
}
```

The `id` parameter can be decorated with `[QueryString]` attribute, but that won't work in my case because the query string contains encrypted version of id which needs to be decrypted before use.

Comment: Put some code in support of your question.

Comment: can't you decode before calling `public MyEntity MyFormView_GetItem(int id)
{//decode first and then call ef}`

Comment: @Șhȇkhaṝ: As I mentioned in the question, this method isn't called by us. The framework calls it indirectly once you specify it as the `SelectMethod` for your `FormView`.